# Selenium driver having issue while saving file

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am giving the default file path while initializing chrome driver but instead of saving at default location it is saving at Download folder. i also changed the default value in chrome setting but still it is saving in download folder.

```
            ChromeOptions chrome = new ChromeOptions();
            _chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(_config.ReadConfig(VanityRedirect_Constants.ChromeFilePath));
            _chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = false;
            chrome.AddArguments("--test-type");
            chrome.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
            chrome.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
            chrome.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", true);
            chrome.AddUserProfilePreference("download.directory_upgrade", true);
            chrome.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", "Some Path");
            chrome.AddUserProfilePreference("safebrowsing.enabled", false);
            _driver = new ChromeDriver(_chromeDriverService, chrome, VanityRedirect_Constants.ChromeLoadTimeVanity);
```

Can some please help me with this issue?

The above code is working fine in one server but able to download on specific path in another server.
It is opening up a windows dialogue box i am giving a path there. now in one server it downloading on given path but once using the same code in another server it is downloading in download path only. 
This is a new issue i guess, not able to figure out the solution for it. Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Exact syntax I dont know in c sharp, but in java code is like that

For Chromedriver try out with:

```
String downloadFilePath = "/path/to/download";
HashMap<String, Object> chromePref = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePref.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePref.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilePath );
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePref);
DesiredCapabilities des_cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
des_cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
des_cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(des_cap);
```

Comment: the solution is not helping